# Calling a function that uses argparse

Tags: python, argparse

how do I call a function that uses `argparse` through another function.

```
def func():
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('env_name', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--exp_name', type=str, default='vpg')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    ~~~ other code here that uses 'args'~~~

def wrap_func()
    func(ARGUMENT_PASSING_NOT_VIA_CMD)

wrap_func()
```

I want to debug it as well so `os.system(...)` isn't good for me.

Comment: Since the whole purpose of using `argparse` is to parse the `sys.argv` provided via a system call, the full test must use such a call.  But you can use `args = parser.parse_args(argv)` where `argv` is a list of strings that emulates a command line.  If that `argv` is `None`, it uses the `sys.argv`.  Is that enough to get you started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you can just add a list of arguments to your `func` function which is then passed on to `parse.parse_args()`. And maybe you should move the `import argparse` to the beginning of the script with other imports.

```
def func(arg_list):
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('env_name', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--exp_name', type=str, default='vpg')
    args = parser.parse_args(arg_list)

    ~~~ other code here that uses 'args'~~~

def wrap_func()
    func(list_of_arguments_you_want_to_pass)

wrap_func()
```

You can find some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090479/python-argparse-pass-values-without-command-line).