# python argparse - pass file without using command line

Tags: python, django, argparse

I want to pass file using form-data to the argparse.
But i'm not getting how to pass file to the argparse without using command-line.
I also gone through the [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090479/python-argparse-pass-values-without-command-line] this solution but this is not helpful for me.

I want to pass file using form-data.

this is my code:

```
#views.py
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def capital_gains():
    parser = argument_parser.get_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
  
    open_lots, sells = loader.load_transactions(args.filename)
    closed_lots = collections.defaultdict(list)

    for symbol, symbol_sells in sells.items():
      closed_lots[symbol] = logic.process_sells(
                         open_lots[symbol], 
                         symbol_sells, 
                         args.wash_sales)

    output = formatter.format(
        closed_lots,
        open_lots,
        args.decimal_places,
        args.shares_decimal_places,
        args.totals)
    
    data = {
            "data": output
        }
    return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

#argument_parser.py

def get_parser():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      usage='%(prog)s [<options>] [--] <input file>',
      description='Capital gains calculator')

  parser.add_argument(
      'filename',
      type=str,
      help=argparse.SUPPRESS,
      metavar='<input file>')

  parser.add_argument(
      '-d',
      '--decimal-places',
      dest='decimal_places',
      type=int,
      default=0,
      help='round $ to %(metavar)s decimal places; default: % 
          (default)s',
      metavar='<n>')

  parser.add_argument(
      '-s',
      '--shares-decimal-places',
      dest='shares_decimal_places',
      type=int,
      default=0,
      help='round shares to %(metavar)s decimal places; default: % 
      (default)s',
      metavar='<n>')

  parser.add_argument(
      '-t',
      '--totals',
      action='store_true',
      help='output totals')

  parser.add_argument(
      '-v',
      '--verbose',
      action='store_true',
      help='verbose output')

  parser.add_argument(
      '-w',
      '--wash-sales',
      dest='wash_sales',
      action=argparse_extensions.NegatableStoreTrueAction,
      help='identify wash sales and adjust cost basis; default: % 
     (default)s',
      default=True)

  return parser
```

can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a sample data? What is form data?

Comment: form-data means key-value pair, i need to pass file from postman

Comment: How are you calling this script and providing command line arguments?  That function def doesn't tell us enough.

Comment: I added my API script @hpaulj